# nuxt3 error while running the application

Tags: vuejs3, npx, nuxtjs3

I hope you are fine. I have created a nuxt app by the command of 'npx nuxi init ' and in the app directory I have done the command 'npm i' and 'npm run dev'; but when when the project runs it show me the error in the image below.
[image]
I will thank if anyone give a piece of advice to solve this.
Thanks.

---

Comment: You're using Windows I guess? Please make a search about that one, some questions already got they answers regarding that one.

Comment: Sorry, but I want to solve this problem without reinstalling my windows

Comment: I don't think that this is the actual solution anyway.